# Facebook php :How To Skip an Warning

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fatal-error

I wrote a facebook php program to post in 10 friends wall.
But If some friends does not allow others to post in their wall i get the following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#210) User not visible thrown in
```

So the Code stops in middle.
I need to ignore the warning if some kind of error occurs and continue the loop.thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a try .. catch block and handle the `OAuthException`

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Mark my answer as the right one if you are happy with the answer when possible :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use FQL to check if the current user *can* post to their friend’s wall upfront – something like

```
SELECT uid, username, can_post FROM user WHERE uid IN
  (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

And if you’d like to only select those friends that allow the user to post in the first place, you can add `AND can_post` to the WHERE clause.